# Querying two taxonomies with tax_query not woking

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a two custom taxonomies:

- Type
- Product

`Type` can be the following:

1. Blog
2. Case study
3. Webinar

`Subject` can be:

1. Indoor
2. Outdoor

I have two drop down menus in WordPress backend where a user can select what `type` and `subject` they want to show from `resources` (my custom post type).

Say, for example, the following posts exist in `resources`:

- **Post 1**: Tagged with `type` blog and `subject` outdoor.
- **Post 2**: Tagged with `type` blog and `subject` indoor.
- **Post 3**: Tagged with `subject` indoor.

The user can either filter by `type` or `subject`. By this I mean not both are required, only one can be selected. But, if the user does choose both a `type` and `subject`, I want it to display posts with both tags.

**Current approach:**

```
$args = array(  
  'post_type' => 'resources',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 8,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'type',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $resource_type,
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'subject',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $resource_subject,
    ),
  ),
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'type',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $resource_type,
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'subject',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $resource_subject,
    ),
  )

);
```

- `$resource_type`: Is the variable holding the dropdown value for
  `type`.
- `$resource_subject`: Is the variable holding the dropdown
  value for `subject`.

**Current results:**

- When filtering by `subject` alone - it works.
- When filtering by `type` alone - it works.
- When filtering with both - it doesn't work. I.e. I've filtered by `type` blog and `subject` indoor and it is showing me `subject` outdoor posts.

Alternatively, the following works when querying both, but does not work when only choosing one:

```
 $args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'resources',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $card_count,
    'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'type',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => $resource_type,
      ),
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'subject',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => $resource_subject,
      ),
    )

  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add another `tax_query` to the args, the last `tax_query` will replace the previous `tax_query`.

But anyway, if these are the criteria:

1. When filtering by `type` alone, show only `resources` posts in that `type`.
2. When filtering by `subject` alone, show only `resources` posts in that `subject`.
3. When filtering by `type` *and* `subject`, show only `resources` posts which are assigned to *both* `type` and `subject`.

Then try this:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'resources',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
);

// Filtering by both 'type' and 'subject'.
if ( $resource_type && $resource_subject ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $resource_type,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'subject',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $resource_subject,
        ),
    );
}
// Filtering by 'type' only.
elseif ( $resource_type && ! $resource_subject ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $resource_type,
        ),
    );
}
// Filtering by 'subject' only.
elseif ( $resource_subject ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'subject',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $resource_subject,
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I was after. Thank you :)